# Which authentication provider should I use for bot?

Tags: c#, bots, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a bot in c#.net and deployed that bot in teams, I want to conference booking in bot by using graph API, so which auth provider should I create?

[image: error]

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth Here are some providers, which one meets your requirement?

Comment: User interactive or non-user interactive?

Comment: @TonyJu user is interactive

Comment: I think you should use Public Client Provider(Interactive authentication provider).

Comment: @TonyJu I had used username password, interactive provider but it gives the same error "  object does not contain." as shown in image at create method  IPublicClientApplication public client application = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .Build();
UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()              .WithUsernamePassword(email, password)
.GetAsync();

Comment: `WithRedirectUri()` isn't needed for public client provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't reproduce your issue. Here is the working sample on my side.

**Using Interactive authentication provider**

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;

namespace AzureTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create("cbc3***-ac27-4532-802d-303998a6e712")
                .Build();

            InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication,scopes);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
            User me = graphClient.Me.Request()
                                .GetAsync().Result;
                Console.Write(me.DisplayName);
        }

    }
}
```

**Using Confidential Client Providers**

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;

namespace AzureTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create("")
                .WithRedirectUri("")
                .WithClientSecret("") 
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

You need to check **include prerelease** when search the package.

[image]

Comment: I got the error at Namespace "Auth" does not exist in the namespace "Microsoft graph" missing assembly reference at using Microsoft.Graph.Auth; I search for Microsoft.Graph.Auth NuGet package, but it is not found

Comment: also I get an error The type namespace interactiveAuthenticationProvider could not be found? Missing directive or an assembly reference

Comment: i have added this packages using bot framework 4 project Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client(5.2.7) Microsoft.AspNetCoreApp(2.1.1)  Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core(4.6.2)  Microsoft.Graph(1.21.0)  Microsoft.Graph.Core(1.20.0) Microsoft.Identity.Client(4.8.1)

Comment: @Priya You need to check `include prerelease` when search the package.

Comment: which authentication provider should I use in a bot to list calendar view in c#

Comment: Worth to mention that **Microsot.Graph.Auth** library is not going to leave prerelease stage at all. [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9137)

Answer (score 3):

Now the Microsoft.Graph.Auth library has been marked as deprecated, so the accepted answer maybe is not valid anymore for someone (like me).

Now you need to use Azure.Identity Nuget package and `InteractiveBrowserCredential` instead of `InteractiveAuthenticationProvider`.

Example using Microsoft.Graph.Auth (DEPRECATED NOW):

```
string[] scopes = {"User.Read"};

IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .Build();

InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                .GetAsync();
```

Example using TokenCredential class

```
string[] scopes = {"User.Read"};

InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions interactiveBrowserCredentialOptions = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions() {
                ClientId = clientId
};
InteractiveBrowserCredential interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(interactiveBrowserCredentialOptions);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveBrowserCredential, scopes); // you can pass the TokenCredential directly to the GraphServiceClient

User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                .GetAsync();
```

Examples are taken from: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v4.md